# How to tell if Android app has been terminated

Tags: android

When debugging an app in Android Studio, if I have an onDestroy method in the main activity and then hit the Back button, onDestroy will get called. However, Android Studio's still shows debugging. What isn't clear is whether this is only showing a debug connection between Android Studio and the device. If I go to App > Settings and force the app to close, the debugging session is terminated. This makes it seem like my app was still running in spite of onDestroy being called. But I have read elsewhere that Android will keep an app in memory for performance reasons. If the user wants to restart the app right away and the app hasn't been garbage collected, apparently it is more efficient to just restart the app that was previously destroyed.

But this raises the question as to whether you can really tell if your app has really been terminated when you press the Back button on the main activity. If onDestroy is called, does this really mean it has been terminated? I understand that you could hold a reference to some object in your code that doesn't get released but onDestroy can still get called but the app remains unterminated due to the referenced object that prevents it from being garbage collected.

Even if you write a bare bones app that does nothing but show a blank activity and hit the Back button, the heap still shows references. So I'm at a loss as to how you can tell with certainty that your app has been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

> This makes it seem like my app was still running in spite of onDestroy being called.

The sooner you stop thinking in terms of "app", the more success you will have as an Android developer.

In this case, you seem to be conflating "app" with "process". [Your process will continue running for some time, even when you have no UI in the foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

> But this raises the question as to whether you can really tell if your app has really been terminated when you press the Back button on the main activity.

An "app" is not terminated. A process is terminated. Your process will not be terminated immediately when the user leaves your UI by any means (BACK, HOME, whatever).

> If onDestroy is called, does this really mean it has been terminated?

It means that whatever component `onDestroy()` was called on was destroyed, such as an `Activity` or `Service`.

> So I'm at a loss as to how you can tell with certainty that your app has been terminated.

Android does not inform you when your process will be terminated, as there are many possible reasons for the process being terminated, including the user telling Android to get rid of your process.

Comment: Sorry but I don't agree with that. Android knows quite well whether your app is still running. This is very obvious when you go to App Settings and it allows you to kill the app. The question is whether that information is available to apps that need to interrogate an app's presence or lack thereof. You're also missing the point. The point is about telling whether your app is alive due to some unreleased reference or because Android is keeping it alive for performance reasons.

Comment: @AndroidDev: "The question is whether that information is available to apps that need to interrogate an app's presence or lack thereof" -- by definition, if your code is running, you have a process running. "The point is about telling whether your app is alive due to some unreleased reference" -- there is no such concept. Now you are conflating in-process garbage collection with OS-level process management.